# spring web application jboss as 7.1.1 performance optimization

Tags: performance, spring, jboss, slowdown

I am deploying spring mvc 3.2.3 web application in jboss AS 7.1.1 in standalone mode. I am communicating with another jboss server that is hosting webservices. Interestingly if i call a JAX-WS webservice from soap for a certain amount of data it returs in 0.6 seconds.

But from my code i get the same data in 3 seconds. There is nothing in between the service call at least from coding point of view that is causing the extra time.

Apart from that, after retriving the data and to show them in the webpage is taking more time. I have included the following line in the java_opts in standalone.conf.bat file

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:MaxHeapSize=1024M"
```

It would be great to know what should be done to increase the speed.

My machine has 3GB of ram. core 2 duo machine, 32 bit windows 7 os.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also felt the need to optimize our jboss performance. I researched alot and found the following info if that could help you out:

The default memory page size in Linux is 4kb. When you’re allocating a lot of memory to an application, this results in many different pages being managed – and thus, a performance loss in managing so many different pages.

I did below  changes to enable large pages at the JVM layer, as well as at the OS layer – to ensure that we can give the system as high of performance as possible.

you can find the clear cut steps here :
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Java_Virtual_Machine_Tuning-Large_Page_Memory.html